# XMLImport Callback

Tags: ms-access, asynchronous, vba

Hi I am using MSAccess (2003) and retrieving an XML recordset from an URL successfully in a macro.

The trouble is the macro and the vba seem to be asynchronous meaning I need a callback on the retrieved xml to continue processing it. I can seem to find anything on the net for a basic VBA callback (I have found stuff on dll's but I am not using these). Does anyone have the missing piece in my puzzle please?

```
Const acAppendData = 2

Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Scripts\Test.mdb"

objAccess.ImportXML "http://api.com/api", acAppendData
```

Comment: It would still be asynchronous - My issue is I need to know when the xml has finished importing into the table and then I can work on it in VBA

Comment: What behavior are you seeing that leads you to believe it's asynchronous?  I just ran a test, pulling xml from a w3c sample `Application.ImportXML "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml", acStructureAndData`, then immediately opening the resulting table as a recordset and it worked as expected (synchronously waiting until the import succeeds before moving to the next line of code).

Comment: Did you open the resultset immediately in the same VBA function?

Comment: Yes, the very next instruction.  Where are you running the code from, by the way?  I'm running it from inside the Access database.  I'll post it as an answer for you to compare against.

Comment: I'm running it from the latest version of Access but the intention is to make it compatible with access 2003

Answer (score 1):

I was able to run the following successfully in Access:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Application.ImportXML "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml", acStructureAndData
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("PLANT")
    rs.MoveLast
    Debug.Print rs.RecordCount
End Sub
```

The .xml file is public, so you should be able to test this without modification.

Comment: @Herb, were you able to run this test?  I'd be curious to see if maybe your issue is the fact that you used "CreateObject".

Answer (score 0):

A method I used to solving this was to use a do while loop querying the resultant table until a record count > 0 was returned and delaying each repeat by 1 second